# Translating sentences with causality into logical propositions

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The author says that the sentence in *a)* is impossible to translate into the language of logic, but it is possible for the sentence in *c)*. And I can not understand why, the second sentence is about the same causality effect: the first sentence connects *not setting an alarm clock* with *oversleeping*, and the second sentence connects *studying hard* with *getting an A*.

What could prevent me from claiming that the causal connection in *c)* is beyond the truth value of the components?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Nothing; the field of causal logic does indeed exist. See Max Urchs: On the Logic of Event-Causation. _Studia Logica_ 53 (1994)

Comment: Agree with Jon.  Perhaps you should say "impossible to translate directly into sequential logic", although the term "directly" is somewhat open to interpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These look like Paul Teller's suggested on-line answers to questions on p. 56 of his book.

I agree with you: (i) 'You will sleep too late unless you set your alarm' and (ii) 'You won't get an A in this course unless you study hard' look pretty much on a par to me.

Now, you could arguably take two lines:

> (A) Say that **both** are naturally read as causal claims: setting the
>   alarm will causally prevent you from sleeping too late, studying hard will causally prevent you from not getting an A.
>
> (B) Say that strictly speaking **neither** is a causal claim, what is literally said
>   is no more than a truth-functional disjunction, even if the natural reason which someone might have
>   for making the truth-functional claim is (in each case) a relevant background
>   causal belief.

Compare: "Either you set the alarm, or you don't set the alarm and will oversleep": your *reason* for saying that may be a casual belief, but arguably what you *say*, the literal content of the message, is just truth-functional: the suggestion in (B) is that it's like that with "unless" claims. And I think that there's something to be said for taking line (B).

But I honestly, with due respect to Teller, can't see any good reason for confidently treating (i) and (ii)  *differently*.

Comment: I agree with your point that there is no objective reason to treat them differently, but I think the author might be (subconciously?) treating (A) as causal because the intent of the statement is that you can control whether the alarm is set, and that control directly implies control over whether you wake up, but with (B) the common language interpretation isn't that a control over studying directly implies that you can control your grade, it is a necessary condition but not a controlling condition...

Comment: ...  Either way, I think the difference between sequential and causal logic is more complex than this example suggests.

Comment: Yes I guess something like that is going on ...though note we can coherently say 'You will sleep too late unless you set your alarm (and even then, it might not wake you)' just as we can say  'You won't get an A in this course unless you study hard (and even then, your work might not be good enough)'.